# Problem with if statement, not getting back anything but seconds when after seconds I should be gettings minutes hours and days

Tags: java, android

I need help with the following logic, I can't seem to get the correct result. I need the logical play out of things--seconds, then past 59 seconds for it to read back minutes, then past 59 minutes for it to read back hour, then hours, past 24 hours it should say day ago, and past day ago it should read back days ago.

Like I said, the logical flow of things. Can soemeone tell me why my if statement doesn't return anything back besides seconds? After it gets to 59 seconds it restars with seconds, doesn't transition into minutes.

What am I missing?

```
//SECOND WAY

        //Current timestamp
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        long ts = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

        //Getting comment timestamp from database
        long timestampOfComment = comment.getTimestamp();

        long duration = ts - timestampOfComment;

        long diffInSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration);
        long diffInMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration);
        long diffInHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(duration);
        long diffInDays = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(duration);

        Log.d("SECONDS", diffInSeconds + " seconds ago");
        Log.d("MINUTES", diffInMinutes + " minutes ago");
        Log.d("HOURS", diffInHours + " hours ago");
        Log.d("DAYS", diffInDays + " days ago");

        if (diffInSeconds == 0) {
            holder.timestamp.setText("Just now");
        } else if (diffInSeconds != 0 && diffInSeconds < 59) {
            holder.timestamp.setText(diffInSeconds + " seconds ago");
        } else if (diffInSeconds != 0 && diffInSeconds > 59) {
            holder.timestamp.setText(diffInMinutes + " minutes ago");
        } else if (diffInSeconds != 0 && diffInSeconds > 59 && diffInMinutes > 59 && diffInHours == 1) {
            holder.timestamp.setText(diffInHours + " hour ago");
        } else if (diffInSeconds != 0 && diffInSeconds > 59 && diffInMinutes > 59 && diffInHours != 1 && diffInHours > 1) {
            holder.timestamp.setText(diffInHours + " hours ago");
        } else if (diffInSeconds != 0 && diffInSeconds > 59 && diffInMinutes > 59 && diffInHours != 1 && diffInHours > 1 && diffInDays == 1) {
            holder.timestamp.setText(diffInDays + " day ago");
        } else if (diffInSeconds != 0 && diffInSeconds > 59 && diffInMinutes > 59 && diffInHours != 1 && diffInHours > 1 && diffInDays != 1 && diffInDays > 1) {
            holder.timestamp.setText(diffInHours + " days ago");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

diffSeconds will never be > 60 since you’re using % 60. So it will go from 58,59,0,1... and so on

Comment: I wasn't sure about the %. I looked it up and just understood that it wasn't the actual difference between the two dates. Is this method better? I just updated the code.

Comment: % returns the remainder of a division. If you divide 25%4, it will return 1 but it will never return greater than 3. That’s what you were calculating there. If you wanted to use that method, you could have used an if statement such as if (diffSeconds==0) diffMinutes++;

Comment: The current method that I have is better?

Comment: Both should work. It should be a matter of which one you’re most comfortable with

Comment: Okay Thanks The second one is better for me. I have to research some the %. It's usage is a little confusing to me. Anyways thanks!

Comment: You mind if we chat real quick? I'm getting 75 minutes instead of 1 hour... Not sure why.

Comment: you mean for `long diffInMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration);` ?

Comment: No I just mean the logic. The if statement isn't giving me back 1 hour if minutes > 59. That sort of thing. Did I over complicate the if statement?

Comment: That's it basically. I am just playing around with the if statement to try to get it to say 1 hour ago or 2 hours ago instead of 91 minutes or 120 minutes... How can I tweak it?

Comment: Just now, seconds ago, minute ago, minutes ago is fine, and then after it passes the 59 minute mark it should say 1 hour ago, but it doesn't. It currently says 78 minutes ago or 91 minutes ago when those both should say **1 hour ago** and so on.. not 91 minutes ago

Comment: `if (diffMinutes==60) { diffMinutes=0; diffHours++;` try this. This way, when there are 60 minutes, the value will be reset to 0 and the value for the hours should increase

Answer (score 1):

Your answer JBM:

```
if(diffInDays > 0){ 
holder.timestamp.setText(diffInDays + " days ago"); 
}else if(diffInHours > 0){ 
holder.timestamp.setText(diffInHours + " hours ago"); 
}else if(diffInMinutes > 0){ 
holder.timestamp.setText(diffInMinutes + " minutes ago"); 
}else if(diffInSeconds > 0){ 
holder.timestamp.setText(diffInSeconds + " seconds ago"); 
}else { 
holder.timestamp.setText("Just now"); 
}
```